# Music player for huge library

Tags: 18.04, music-player

I am planning to move from Win 10 to Ubuntu 18.04.
All my music (~ 350k files, 450 GB) is being stored on my server.
On my current Windows computer I am using MediaMonkey as it is able to deal with so many music files.

Is there an equivalent tool for Ubuntu?

Comment: Rythmbox is Ubuntu's default music player. Does that not work for you? http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2019/01/rhythmbox-3-4-3-released-with-numerous-bug-fixes/

Comment: I have tried that via a live usb drive but it hang up several times. Not sure if this is because of the usb drive or if Rythmbox is not capable of so much files.

Comment: Have you followed the link to update to the latest version?

Comment: Yes - I did and it's worth to give it a try as soon as a moved to Ubuntu completly.
I just mentioned my yesterdays experience and thoughts.

Comment: It has a lot of features and may avoid the issues you mentioned if you work on a substantive installation rather than live usb. In case you haven't read it, here is the official documentation page https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Rhythmbox I can post this as an answer if you find it helpful.

Comment: @Graham: Yes, it would be great if you could mark this as an answer to my issue.
I'll give it a try as soon as I am back at home.

Comment: Done. If you would be so kind as to mark it as the accepted answer, it will help other uses when searching for similar answers. Thanks.

Comment: you want a player or a server for your audio files?

Comment: @AlexOnLinux: A player but I'll try the suggested solution from Graham.
But feel free to recommend any players you might find suitable for my request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rhythmbox is the Gnome's default music player.

Read [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Rhythmbox) explanation from the Official Ubuntu Documentation.

Version 3.4.3 has been released with numerous bug fixes.

Not least of which includes:

- Improved Android plugin to work better with Samsung and Android 9 devices
- Replaced status bar with floating bar as used by Nautilus
- Fixed crash when store request processing fails
- Fixed crashes when editing auto playlist sorted by Location / Bitrate
- Fixed crashes when insert a cd
- Fixed issue that can not transfer songs to phone over MTP

In order to install the latest PPA and benefit from the new version, open a terminal and run the following command:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntuhandbook1/apps
```

Then launch Software Updater to upgrade the music player packages

[image]

You can purge the PPA which will also downgrade Rhythmbox to the stock version (3.4.2-4ubuntu1) via the command in terminal:

```
sudo apt install ppa-purge && sudo ppa-purge ppa:ubuntuhandbook1/apps
```

Comment: Does Rhythmbox do gapless playback nowadays? Last time I looked, it didn't, and a music player that does not do that is not a music player for me.

Comment: @vanadium Seems so according to this Wikipedia posting Gapless playback

"Enabling the crossfading backend option with a duration of 0.0 switches Rhythmbox into gapless playback mode for music formats that support it. Gapless playback is not enabled by default." https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhythmbox#Gapless_playback